# How to debug a single shell command call, viewing arguments accurately?

Tags: bash, debugging, sh

When I'm debugging a script, I'll often take a line I'm not quite sure about e.g.:

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder "$3" -format UDRO -fs APFS -volname "$1" -ov "$2"
```

and simply change it to:

```
echo hdiutil create -srcfolder "$3" -format UDRO -fs APFS -volname "$1" -ov "$2"
```

Then when I run my script the first time, it won't run the (potentially incorrect) command but I can see it and check that it looks correct… and maybe even copy/paste it to run it manually.

But this isn't reliable/correct if any of the arguments have spaces in them. The `echo` shows spaces *within* an argument just the same as the separator *between* arguments.

I found the `set -x` command which helpfully logs every command **with** arguments properly escaped! That's what I'm using for now, but it's pretty broad-grained (noisy across a large script where I'm focused on just one line) and doesn't prevent the actual un-verified command from running.

Is there a quick/clean way to do this for just one line. Or some other trick using commonly available commands — maybe some combination of `env` and `printf` or whatnot? or a dedicated command that got included for basically this purpose?

Ideally it'd be something I could just pre-pend to the line in question which would both "comment it out" *and* show me **exactly** what it *would* have done if enabled.

Comment: You can do `set -x` right before the line you're interested in, and `set +x` after.

Comment: If you want a more comprehensive debugging solution than `set -x` then you could use `bashdb` which can be installed via MacPorts or Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf %q`:

```
#!/bin/bash
run() {
  printf "%q " "$@"  # show each argument shell escaped
  printf '\n'
  (( dryrun )) || "$@" # optionally run the command
}

dryrun=1
run hdiutil create -srcfolder "$3" -format UDRO -fs APFS -volname "$1" -ov "$2"
```